# How do I retrieve the actual query directly from a ADODB.Recordset?

Tags: asp-classic, ado

I'm using a command to create a new record set:

```
set rsQuery = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
```

Once the rsQuery.open command is performed, how do I determine which query was fired by only looking at the Recordset or rsQuery object?  The reason I need to do this is b/c I may have many case statement that open a querystring based on a case.  Not only do I want the result from the query, I just want to print out the query without having to create a response.write command for each query command.

example:

```
case "1"
  rsQuery.open "Select * from tblA", conn
case "2"
  rsQuery.open "Select * from tblB", conn
```

etc...

Desired Result:
response.write "My Result:" & rsQuery.Query?

```
My Result: Select * from tblA
```

Comment: I figured it out.  First one to add I'll put as answer.  Its this resposne.write "My Result:" & rsQuery.Source .  thx

Comment: Why not just add your answer? You did the work....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Source method:

```
response.write "My Result:" & rsQuery.Source
```

Answer (score 2):

you could do this:

```
case "1"
  myquery = "Select * from tblA"
case "2"
  myquery = "Select * from tblB"

...
  rsQuery.open myquery , conn
  response.write myquery
```

Comment: Thanks. In my case there is no interim qry string object, I need to get it from the result set.